# reading inbox with IMAP is not very fast

Tags: php, performance, imap

I am using IMAP to read my last 3 unseen emails.
I am using php. The email provider is fastmail.
I use the following approach.
I get the emails where $d is yesterday.

```
$s = 'SUBJECT "New email from " SINCE "'.$d.'" UNSEEN';          
$emails = imap_search($this->conn,$s);
```

$emails is an array of email ids.
I loop over them like so:

```
foreach ($emails as $index => $i) {
    $message   = imap_body($this->conn, $i) . '<br>';
    $overview  = imap_fetch_overview($this->conn, $i, 0);
    $structure = imap_fetchstructure($this->conn, $i);

    if (!empty($overview[0])) {
        $subject = $overview[0]->subject;
    }

    //from this point i get some html and i just process it.
    $mes = imap_body($this->conn, $i);
}
```

How can i make the whole process faster? Any ideas?
I am not an expert in IMAP.
Is there any way that i can just get the text body, and not the rest of the email?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean "only the subject" instead of "only the text body"? The body is usually the biggest part of a mail. Did you try to profile your code with xdebug to find out which function slows the performance? Is caching an option?

Comment: @FabianH. I did not profile it with xDebug. No, i did not mean only the subject. I meant only the body text. Because in an email there are also headers, all kind of different headers which i dont need. Also usually a picture, some logo..I need only the body text.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. Did you try to remove all within your loop but `$mes = imap_body($this->conn, $i);`?